# Swagger SpringFox Giving 404

Tags: java, documentation, swagger-2.0, springfox

Please find the config details.

Its a spring application

Dependency

```
    //swagger for api documentation
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2')
```

Code

```
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myntra.catalog.service")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Spring REST APIs")
                .description("Catalog Service APIs")
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Getting this log in build
`05:35:54.998 INFO  springfox.documentation.spring.web.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]   - Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]`

But 
**/v2/api-docs is giving 404 **

Getting the above error. Can someone please help here.